# MCP2221 circuit not showing up in device manager, let alone as a COM port

Tags: usb, ftdi

I have made a simple custom board based on an Atmega168A and a MCP2221 for the USB bridge. I have successfully programmed the Atmega to shine the on-board LED and display "hello" on the Serial bus (using an ArduinoUNO as ICSP) with bootloader burnt ([Minicore](https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore), if that matters), but when I proceeded to disconnect the ICSP circuit and connect the on-board USB link (J3 on the schematic) nothing happens. Nothing in Windowsw's device manager.

I used a MCP2221 not long ago with the same computer, using the same subcircuit ("USB-UART" block on the schematic), and it used to work just fine.

What did I miss? I do not think this belongs in Arduino SE, my guts tell me something's wrong with my circuit somehow.

Circuit  below, obviously design-rules-checked so accurately describing the actual PCB (manufactured by Eurocircuits). Wire labels are all net names. The resonator is not populated (I used the internal 8MHz oscillator when programming), and the switch is used to reset the uC when programming via USB.
[image]

Comment: The full res was linked right above the picture but I updated the picture to link to thePDF when clicked

Comment: You're right - done

Comment: It seems really strange to have caps on your USB data lines, why do you have those? Can you share how you routed the USB D+/D- lines from the connector to the MCP2221? Did you route them respecting differential pair impedance? Trace lengths?

Comment: BTW, Microchip has a [breakout board](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002282A.pdf) for this, I'd look at the schematic on page 26, as well as the routing on the following pages to see how Microchip recommends a design be made. If you notice, they don't have any resistors or caps on the USB data lines. I'd replace the resistors with 0R links and remove the caps and see if this improves anything.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had soldered by mistake an Attiny841 instead of the MCP2221... Same package, and the Atmel's marking is incredibly difficult to read!